# Failed to register: TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not object

Tags: node.js, blockchain

I am trying to connect to IBM BLockchain instance through node.js code

I am getting the following error:
Successfully loaded admin from persistence
Failed to register: TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not object

Comment: Looks you're passing an object as `url` instead of string. Can you provide the code?

Comment: it was resolved. the issue was due to library